# How to write that the condition $\lim_{|t|\to +\infty} F(t)=0$ is false?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^n$ be a continuous function such that
$$(1) \qquad \lim_{|t|\to +\infty} F(t)=0.$$

What does it mean that $(1)$ is false?

I would have said what follows.

Assume that $(1)$ is false. It means that exist $\epsilon>0$ and $(t_n)_n$ with $t_n\to +\infty$ such that $|F(t_n)|>\varepsilon \quad\forall n\in\mathbb N$.

This statement was marked as an error in the homework sheet I submitted to the lecturer last week.
Anyone can please help me what is wrong?

Comment: "... with $\lvert t_n\rvert\to\infty$...", although in (1) writing $\lvert t\rvert\to\pm\infty$ instead of $\lvert t\rvert\to +\infty$ was weird in the first place.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio, sorry, it was a mistake.

Comment: It means that there exists $\epsilon>0$ and $|t_n|\to \infty$ such that $|F(t_n)|>\epsilon$ for infinitely many $n$

Comment: So, the mistake was that I wrote $t_n\to \infty$ instead of $|t_n|\to \infty$?

Comment: Yes. However, the grader may also have marked it wrong since you said for all $n$. Of course, this is not wrong, but we are not the grader, so can't tell you definitively

Comment: It's also possible that they wanted you to write the straight negation of the *definition* of (1), instead of the sequential criterion version; i.e. there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $R>0$ there exists $t_R$ with $|t_R|>R$ and $|F(t_R)|\geq \epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks everyone!